# Como subir una imagen con fondo transparente a laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Veran, necesito subir una imagen transparente con laravel, ya tengo la subida de archivos de a la siguiente manera:

```
for($i=0;$i<count(Input::file('imagen'));$i++){            
    if(file_exists(Input::file('imagen')[0])){
           $file=Input::file('imagen')[$i];
           $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
           $ctime=$file->getCTime();
           $nombre=base64_encode($nombre.$ctime);
           $year=Carbon::now()->year;


           $path=public_path().'/imagenes/'.$year.'/'.$nombre;
           $pathmini=public_path().'/imagenes/'.$year.'/miniatura/'.$nombre;

           $image=Image::make($file);
           $miniatura=Image::make($file);
           $miniatura->resize(100,100);
           $image->save($path.'.jpg');

    }
}
```

**Pero la imagen subida que inicialmente tiene un fondo transparente se cambia a color blanco.**

`Image` es la libreria [Intervention/Image](http://image.intervention.io), con el cual trate de utilizar su funcion `opacity(0)` antes de guardar, pero este tardaba demasiado al punto que salida **30seg limit exced** o algo asi, para no tener este problema agregue otras tres lineas codigo:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$image=Image::make($file);
$miniatura=Image::make($file);
$miniatura->resize(100,100);
$image->opacity(0);
$image->save($path.'.jpg');
$miniatura->save($pathmini.'.jpg');
```

Pero en este caso no subía **jamas la imagen** espero al menos unos 20min y nada. Solo es una imagen 1.5 MB.

> Como subir una imagen con fondo transparente con laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu error es que tu imagen sin fondo debe estar en formato `png`.
que es el unico formato de imagen web que lo permite.
debes optener el formato de  la imagen con `$file->getClientOriginalExtension()`
y no cambiarlo todos a `jpg`.

**ejemplo:**

```
for($i=0;$i<count(Input::file('imagen'));$i++){            
    if(file_exists(Input::file('imagen')[0])){
           $file=Input::file('imagen')[$i];
           $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
           $ctime=$file->getCTime();
           $nombre=base64_encode($nombre.$ctime);
           $year=Carbon::now()->year;


           $path=public_path().'/imagenes/'.$year.'/'.$nombre;
           $pathmini=public_path().'/imagenes/'.$year.'/miniatura/'.$nombre;

           $image=Image::make($file);
           $miniatura=Image::make($file);
           $miniatura->resize(100,100);
           $image->save($path.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());

    }
}
```